# Not able to get print output with the bash file

Tags: linux, unix, rhel

I have one file named `a.txt` in which I have some 10-15 words in format-
AB
AC
AV

So now I am creating bash file named dir.sh in which I am giving-

```
FILENAME="$1.txt"

LINES=$(cat $FILENAME)

for L in $LINES
do
echo "$L"

printf "\n"

printf "$1_views"

done
```

And when I am running `./dir.sh a`

I am getting output :

```
AB


AC


AV
```

Means I am not able to get output of `echo "$L"` ...... but not able to get output of `printf "$L_views"`
So can someone help me with this like how to get output for `printf "$L_views"`

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Do you want `$1_views` or `$L_views`? Anyway, just wrap the variable name in braces like `${L}_views.

Comment: Use `"${L}_views"`

Comment: Thank you @– underscore_d and @  – Barmar  for your response